# Enable cookies in WinForms webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, cookies, browser

i was trying to make a bot for a facebook game .. the problem is that the user need to login to facebook . i tried to make this with httpwebrequest . everything went fine but i got an error saying my web browser doesn't support cookies

here is the code i used for the httpwebrequest

```
 Dim postData As String = "lsd=AVrFBNXT&display=&enable_profile_selector=&legacy_return=1&next=&profile_selector_ids=&trynum=1&timezone=-120&lgnrnd=163248_FehM&lgnjs=1372203160&email=" & (TextBox1.Text) & "&pass=" & (TextBox2.Text) & "f&default_persistent=1"
    Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php"), HttpWebRequest)
    postreq.Method = "POST"
    postreq.KeepAlive = True
    postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
    postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
    postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postreq.Referer = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php"
    postreq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postreq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempcookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you enabled cookies?

Comment: i am using ordinary .net webbrowser found in the tool box . and this is the point i want to know how to enable cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webbrowser control is essentially an embedded Internet Explorer and thus shares Internet Explorer's settings.

If your IE has cookies enabled then your WebBrowser control has them enabled too and your problem could be elsewhere.

To check your IE settings follow these steps:

1. Choose "Internet Options" under the "Tools" menu on the IE;
2. Select the "Privacy" tab.
3. Click the "Advanced..." button in the "Settings" groupbox.
4. Check the "Override automatic cookie handling" option.
5. Check both "Accept" options.
6. Click "OK"