# VB.Net HttpWebRequest - Transfer cookies from HttpWebRequest to WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net

I want to transfer cookies from HttpWebRequest to WebBrowser.
I tried below code but not working.

My cookie from HttpWebRequest is named : loginPostcookie

Am I setting the parameters of InternetSetCookieEx very well?

```html
<DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function InternetSetCookieEx(url As String, cookieName As String, cookieData As StringBuilder, dwFlags As Int32, lpReserved As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
    
    
    InternetSetCookieEx("https://www.facebook.com/", loginPostcookie.ToString, "TestData=Test;", 0, 0)
    
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Comment: check this out: [How Webrowser Cookies work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309396/enable-cookies-in-winforms-webbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

I use cookies to allow my users to save their user name in a cookie so they don't have to keep typing it in when they log in.  I set and retrieve the cookie with the code below"

```
' Set the cookie when the user checks the checkbox
If CheckBox_SaveUserName.Checked Then
    ' Save whatever username is in the textbox into the cookie
    Dim oCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("SignIn")
    oCookie = New HttpCookie("SignIn", txtUserName.Text)
    oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100)
    Response.AppendCookie(oCookie)
    'Response.Cookies("SignIn")("User") = txtUsername.Text
 Else
     ' To delete the cookie, we expire it.  Browser security won't let use remove it.
     Response.Cookies("SignIn").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-50)
 End If
```

When the user access the log on page, I check for the cookie:

```
' If the signin cookie exists, get the username and check the checkbox
If Not IsNothing(Request.Cookies("SignIn")) Then
    If txtUserName.Text & "" = "" Then
        txtUserName.Text = Request.Cookies("SignIn").Value
        CheckBox_SaveUserName.Checked = True
    End If
End If
```